# Local Storage not working in Cordova 6.2.0 iOS 4.1.1

Tags: ios, cordova, local-storage

I am using local storage to store and retrieve some items in Cordova version 6.2.0 using iOS platform version 4.1.1. I am using          `localStorage.setItem("key", "value");
var value = localStorage.getItem("key");
alert(value);`

But it is not showing any alert. How can I use local storage?

Comment: can you please write proper code snippet so we can get better idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per official [Cordova documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/storage/storage.html), try out the following code:

```
var storage = window.localStorage;
var value = storage.getItem(key); // Pass a key name to get its value.
storage.setItem(key, value) // Pass a key name and its value to add or update that key.
storage.removeItem(key)
```

For retrieving local storage value, you can try the following code:

```
window.localStorage.setItem("key","value");
var value = window.localStorage.getItem("key");
alert(value);
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I used this only but my app freezes. It works well if I remove the local storage code. But the app gets stuck at the screen where I insert the local storage code.

Comment: The problem got solved. I was doing this inside deviceonready function. I changed the location to another function and the app started working. Thanks !!

Comment: mentioned not.. :)